# darkmarket - ImportError: No module named obelisk

Tags: import, module

I just installed the darkmarket from https://github.com/darkwallet/darkmarket on my debian linux.
After installation I run:
1.) ~/darkmarket-master$ ./run_dev.sh
and 
2.) ~/darkmarket-master$ ./run.sh
but I got 
    import obelisk
ImportError: No module named obelisk

just opened two localhost browsers with ports 8888 and 8889 but they don't work.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

darkmarket is a prototype and a demo made in the toronto bitcoin hackathon. I wouldn't use it for anything production ready.

That said you need python-obelisk and an obelisk server:

https://github.com/darkwallet/python-obelisk

https://wiki.unsystem.net/index.php/Obelisk/Servers